# Issues with running Ridge regression

Tags: r, regression

I used to use a package called 'ridge' from Erica Cule to run ridge regression but it seems to have been taken off the CRAN site. Looking through the various help there seems to be at least 2 other packages which can run it (genridge and MASS). However, when I run the analysis I get results which I know are wrong (I compared results against the SPSS Ridge routine, which is long established and I used the same data that I used to compare the ridge package which had the same results as SPSS).

I am using the latest version of R (3.2.3). The data is standard regression type data so all data is on a 7 point semantic scale, there is no missing data (missing data replaced by mean), there is strong correlations between the variables (typically 0.5 and above) so you would expect to see large penalty effects in a ridge regression.

When I run the analysis in both methods, the coefficients basically do not change as lambda increases (only changes to the 4rd decimal place).

Any thoughts as to what is going wrong?

```
###################################
#genridge
###################################

library(genridge)

regdata <- read.csv(file = "Finaldata.csv", na.strings = "#NULL!")

lridge <- ridge(Q13 ~ Q12_1 + Q12_2 + Q12_3 + Q12_4 + Q12_5 + Q12_6 + Q12_7 + Q12_8, data = regdata, lambda = seq(0,5,0.2))
coef(lridge)


###################################
#lm.ridge
###################################

library(MASS)

lridge <- lm.ridge(Q13 ~ Q12_1 + Q12_2 + Q12_3 + Q12_4 + Q12_5 + Q12_6 + Q12_7 + Q12_8, regdata, lambda = seq(0,5,0.2))
lridge$coef
```

Data looks like this

```
serial  Q13 Q12_1   Q12_2   Q12_3   Q12_4   Q12_5   Q12_6   Q12_7   Q12_8
12  6   6   5   5   6   6   6   6   6
13  5   5   6   5   5   3   4   5   4
16  5   6   6   6   5   7   7   4   5
20  7   7   6   6   6   6   6   6   7
22  2   1   4   4   3   4   4   4   4
25  6   6   7   6   6   6   6   6   6
```

Output from genridge

```
        Q12_1       Q12_2     Q12_3     Q12_4       Q12_5     Q12_6      Q12_7     Q12_8
0.0 0.2915857 -0.06272736 0.1030976 0.2877907 -0.02847326 0.1817142 0.08490121 0.1303255
0.2 0.2914957 -0.06265994 0.1031015 0.2877065 -0.02837763 0.1816626 0.08487546 0.1303682
0.4 0.2914057 -0.06259260 0.1031054 0.2876224 -0.02828214 0.1816110 0.08484980 0.1304108
0.6 0.2913159 -0.06252533 0.1031093 0.2875384 -0.02818680 0.1815595 0.08482421 0.1304532
0.8 0.2912262 -0.06245813 0.1031132 0.2874544 -0.02809159 0.1815082 0.08479870 0.1304956
1.0 0.2911365 -0.06239101 0.1031171 0.2873705 -0.02799653 0.1814569 0.08477326 0.1305378
```

Comment: any reason you didn't try `glmnet`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try glmnet R package.

Also if your data size is not huge you could consider ridge regression 
as an augmented ordinary least squares problem

Here is the link which explains the idea well
http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/sta305files/Rudyregularization.pdf